# Remove QSplitter line between widgets

Tags: python, pyqt, qsplitter

I am building a UI and I have a horizontal QSplitter with 2 widgets. I want to remove the line with the dots (.....) between the widgets.

Here is an image to make it clear what I want removed.

[the dots I want gone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUC61.png)
here is some code:
`self.mySplitter = QSplitter(Qt.Horizontal, self)
 self.mySplitter.addWidget(self.widget1)
 self.mySplitter.addWidget(self.mySecondSplitter)
 self.mySplitter.setChildrenCollapsible(False)`

Comment: It looks like you're using a stylesheet. Why not just styling the `QSplitter`, so that it does not show an image?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I'm not using a style sheet for my slitter, since I just instantiate it and never assign it any style sheet or whatever. I'll try to clear the style sheet if anything is in there.

Comment: tried it and didn't work, the dots are still showing.

Comment: What OS are you using? The image you provided doesn't look like native style...

Comment: What stylesheet code are you using?

Comment: Windows 10, and to take out the style sheet I did self.mySplitter.setStyleSheet("")

Comment: Look at my answer please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have applied a stylesheet somewhere in you code. To hide the image, try this:

```
self.mySplitter.setStyleSheet("QSplitter::handle { image: none; }")
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Awesome! This is what I needed. Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad I could help! If you need to style more widgets in future, I recommend to create a file, put all the style definitions in it, read it in Python code and apply it using the above.